# To check the two array of object values based on the respective key?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am trying to compare two array of object values based on the specific key. Two object  has same keys based on that i have to check whether the values are equal or not. One array is actual JSON object and the second one is test data, we have to verify the test data with JSON object and moreover if the test data value is same, it might have some extra space we need to trim that value as well.

```
   var actualObject= [
  {
    "q1": "componentWillMount"
  },
  {
    "q2": "willComponentUpdate"
  },
  {
    "q3": "setState"
  },
  {
    "q4": "componentUpdated"
  }
]

Var testData =[
{q1: "componentWillMount"},
{q2: "willComponentUpdate"},
{q3: " PropTypes"},
{q4: "componentDidMount"}]
```

I will get the testData values from the Html code, on selection of radio buttons. Now i need to check how many answer are correct with actual JSON.

JS Code for it:

```
var marks= 0;
var wrong = 0;
for(var k =0 ; k<actualObject.length;k++){
if(JSON.stringify(actualObject[k]) == JSON.stringify(testData[k])){
    marks++;
}
else {
    wrong++;
}
}
```

```js
var actualObject = [{
    "q1": "componentWillMount"
  },
  {
    "q2": "willComponentUpdate"
  },
  {
    "q3": "setState"
  },
  {
    "q4": "componentUpdated"
  }
]

var testData = [{
    q1: "componentWillMount"
  },
  {
    q2: "willComponentUpdate"
  },
  {
    q3: " PropTypes"
  },
  {
    q4: "componentDidMount"
  }
];

var marks = 0;
var wrong = 0;
for (var k = 0; k < actualObject.length; k++) {
  if (JSON.stringify(actualObject[k]) == JSON.stringify(testData[k])) {
    marks++;
  } else {
    wrong++;
  }
}
console.log(marks, wrong);
```

Actually i would like to take value from each key and compare it with the actualObject.

Comment: would you rephrase it with "current input" and "expected output"? then your code does not include any trim, or whatever....

Comment: From the output in the code snippet, you only need to trim the test data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly something like this should work:

```
Object.entries(testData).forEach(function (entry) {
    if (actualObject[entry[0]] === entry[1].trim()) {
        //answers match
    } else {
        //answers don't match
    }
});
```

If you need to compare regardless of case then change `entry[1].trim()` to `entry[1].trim().toLowerCase()`.

**EDIT:**
Just to remind you that maybe you should add a check whether or not the values in the test data are null/undefined, if they are strings or not, etc.